# How were the bounds of integration changed here in this probability problem on uniform distributions?

Tags: probability, probability-distributions, uniform-distribution

I have the following problem and solution:

[image]

I don't understand how the bounds of integration were changed from 0 to 1, to $x^2$ to 1. I see where $1/\sqrt{y}$ was substituted in for $f(x|y)$ and 1 was substituted in for $g(y)$, but I don't see any justification for changing the bounds.

Comment: Break up the integral of $f(x\mid y)g(y)$ from $0$ to $1$ to the sum of integrals from $0$ to $x^2$ and from $x^2$ to $1$. What is the value of the integrand of the first of these integrals?  (Hint: look at the line above (the one beginning "But...") and read what the line _does not say_ (but expects you to understand implicitly) as well as what th line  says explicitly.

Comment: Well for the author's solution to be true, we must have $\int_0^{x^2} \frac{1}{\sqrt{y}}\cdot1 dy = 0$. However, I got $\int_0^{x^2} \frac{1}{\sqrt{y}}\cdot1 dy = 2\sqrt{x^2}$, so I must be missing something important.

Comment: What I was trying to suggest to you, but you failed to recognize, was that the statement "But $f(x\mid y) \cdots 0 < x < \sqrt{y}$" was implying that for _fixed_ $x \in (0,1)$, $f(x\mid y)$ had value $0$ for $y \in (0,x^2)$. This is explicitly spelled out in the answer by Philip Paine that you have accepted.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The limits of integration are changed because outside of those values the density is equal to zero.

The random variable X is uniform on $(0, \sqrt{y})$ which means that outside of this range the density function is zero. That is the conditional density is,

$  f(x \vert y) = \left\{
  \begin{array}{lr}
    \frac{1}{\sqrt{y}} & : 0 < x < \sqrt{y} , \\
    0 & : \text{otherwise .}
  \end{array}
\right. $

$ 0 < x < \sqrt{y}$ in terms of y is 
 $ x^2 < y $. The conditional density $f(x \vert y )$ is zero outside of this range and hence will not contribute to the value of the integral. The upper limit is still $1$ because $Y \sim Unif(0,1)$. Therefore,

$ f(x) = \int_0^1 f(x \vert y) g(y) \mathrm{d}y = \int_0^{x^2} f(x \vert y) g(y) \mathrm{d}y +  \int_{x^2}^1 f ( x \vert y) g(y) \mathrm{d}y = \int_{x^2}^1 f ( x \vert y) g(y) \mathrm{d}y  . $